# How do I copy a table cell containing a list, and restart the numbering?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some text in a table. The first row is populated with some template text. See screenshot below:

[image: template table]

I want to copy this row, keeping all formatting, and restart the list from 1. See screenshot of expected result:

[image: table with text copied to second row]

For this toy example, I wrote the following code:

```
Sub copyTableData()

    Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.FormattedText.Copy

    Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range.FormattedText.PasteAndFormat (wdListRestartNumbering)
End Sub
```

This retains the formatting, but the numbering continues from the first cell, despite using the option `wdListRestartNumbering`. Also, for some reason, the last list item is not numbered. See screenshot below of the result after running the `copyTableData()` function:
[image: result after running existing code]

Comment: Interesting, when I do a manual copy/paste of text, numbering starts with 1.  One suggestion I found was to use ConvertNumbersToText. That does work in my test. https://superuser.com/questions/1648682/copy-paste-table-with-autonumbering-between-ms-word-documents-while-preserving-n

Comment: And I have no issue with the last line - copies just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are conjectures on my part:

- In this case the wdListRestartNumbering option only applies to the
  last paragraph that's copied.
- If the last numbered paragraph comes immediately before the end of
  cell marker, then the paragraph numbering is lost when you paste
  (This looks a bit like an error in Word because other paragraph
  formatting is copied).
- When you copy and paste the list, all the paragraphs in the new list
  are in the same list as the original list. There, doing something
  like resetting the new list's start number to 1 only affects that
  paragraph as the other paragraphs in the list remain in the original
  list.

The following code seems to deal with all those things in this particular situation, but if for example you have more than one list you would have to do more.

I certainly hope that there is a much simpler solution.

```
Sub copyTableDataExample()

Dim p As Word.Paragraph
Dim r As Word.Range
Dim s As Word.Range
With ActiveDocument
  Set r = .Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range
  r.InsertParagraphAfter
  ' If you "copy" the end of cell marker, the data may end up in the wrong cell, so adjust the end of Range
  r.End = r.End - 1
  Set s = .Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range
  ' Copy
  s.FormattedText = r.FormattedText
  ' Remove the paras we inserted
  r.Characters(r.Characters.Count).Delete
  Set r = Nothing
  s.Characters(s.Characters.Count - 1).Delete
  
  ' look for the first paragraph in a list and split the list
  For Each p In s.Paragraphs
    If p.Range.ListParagraphs.Count = 1 Then
      p.SeparateList
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
  Set s = Nothing
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I've looked over the code and more or less understand how it works except for one thing - why, when deleting the last character from cells, is there a difference in the index? ie. the index for deleting the last character in `r` is `r.Characters.Count` whereas for `s` it's `s.Characters.Count-1`

Comment: @ApexPolenta it is because I have already reduced the length of range r by 1 character using r.End = r.End -1. And I do that because otherwise the "copy" does not work (the text can even be copied into the wrong cell).